# How to use simple_navigation_goals on stdr and rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use simple_navigation_goals(http://wiki.ros.org/ja/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) on stdr and rviz.
But I could not find where should I send the topic.

I use turtlebot sim.
$ roslaunch turtlebot_stdr turtlebot_in_stdr.launch

For example.

```
$ rostopic list
/amcl/parameter_descriptions
/amcl/parameter_updates
/amcl_pose
/clicked_point
/cmd_vel_mux/active
/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller
/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_descriptions
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_updates
/diagnostics
/diagnostics_agg
/diagnostics_toplevel_state
/initialpose
/joint_states
/kobuki_safety_controller/disable
/kobuki_safety_controller/enable
/kobuki_safety_controller/reset
/map
/map_metadata
/map_updates
/mobile_base/commands/velocity
/mobile_base/events/bumper
/mobile_base/events/cliff
/mobile_base/events/wheel_drop
/mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud
/mobile_base_nodelet_manager/bond
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/cost_cloud
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/global_plan
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/local_plan
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/parameter_updates
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/trajectory_cloud
/move_base/NavfnROS/plan
/move_base/cancel
/move_base/current_goal
/move_base/feedback
/move_base/global_costmap/costmap
/move_base/global_costmap/costmap_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/footprint
/move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/clearing_endpoints
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/goal
/move_base/local_costmap/costmap
/move_base/local_costmap/costmap_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/footprint
/move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/clearing_endpoints
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/parameter_updates
/move_base/result
/move_base/status
/move_base_simple/goal
/navigation_velocity_smoother/parameter_descriptions
/navigation_velocity_smoother/parameter_updates
/navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel
/odom
/particlecloud
/robot0/cmd_vel
/robot0/laser_0
/robot0/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/stdr_server/active_robots
/stdr_server/co2_sources_list
/stdr_server/delete_robot/cancel
/stdr_server/delete_robot/feedback
/stdr_server/delete_robot/goal
/stdr_server/delete_robot/result
/stdr_server/delete_robot/status
/stdr_server/register_robot/cancel
/stdr_server/register_robot/feedback
/stdr_server/register_robot/goal
/stdr_server/register_robot/result
/stdr_server/register_robot/status
/stdr_server/rfid_list
/stdr_server/sound_sources_list
/stdr_server/sources_visualization_markers
/stdr_server/spawn_robot/cancel
/stdr_server/spawn_robot/feedback
/stdr_server/spawn_robot/goal
/stdr_server/spawn_robot/result
/stdr_server/spawn_robot/status
/stdr_server/thermal_sources_list
/tf
/tf_static
```

and

```
$ rostopic type  move_base/goal
move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal
$ rostopic type  move_base/current_goal
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped
$ rostopic type  move_base_simple/goal
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped
$ rostopic type /cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
geometry_msgs/Twist
```

In the code,

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;
MoveBaseClient ac("move_base", true);
```

These are no type of MoveBaseAction, so I could not send it.

Please help me.

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248062/how-to-use-simple_navigation_goals-on-stdr-and-rviz/) by [sora](https://answers.ros.org/users/28523/sora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It solved by myself.

In the code,

```
goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map";
```

and on rviz,

```
gloval options/fixed flame = map
```

---

Originally posted by [sora](https://answers.ros.org/users/28523/sora/) with karma: 63 on 2016-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0